# python, pandas - selecting group in multi indexing series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I would like some advice to selecting a group.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q1m9x.png]

for instance, I have try to select warehouse(JobTitle) and PA(loc):

```
fdO2.xs(('Warehouse','PA'))
fdO2.loc[('Warehouse','PA')]
```

and for some reason I get this error:

```
KeyError: ('Warehouse', 'PA')
KeyError: 'PA'
```

any advice?

Comment: Did you try calling `iloc` with the column index for warehouse and PA as arguments? For example, try `fdO2.iloc[:,[WAREHOUSE_IDX,PA_IDX]]`

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html please also consider reading [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: you can provide a sample df with `fdO2.head(20).to_dict('list')`

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the "`Location`" and "`Sum of Spend`" for the `Warehouse` and `PA`:

```
fdO2 = fdO2.loc[(fdO2["JobTitle"]=="Warehouse") & (fdO2["loc"]=="PA"),['Location','Sum of Spend']]
```

Or if you want all the columns for the selected `Warehouse` and `PA`:

```
fdO2 = fdO2.loc[(fdO2["JobTitle"]=="Warehouse") & (fdO2["loc"]=="PA"),:]
```